# Can we retrieve values of the input elements without using forms in java?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I was trying to access values in a **JSP** page.Can I access the values of the Input Elements from **servlet** which are outside the form ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put hidden input values inside the form, and copy the input elements' values on them with javascript when you need.

Or you can use ajax as they suggested in this question:

[Sending text-field value to server without form tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846996/sending-text-field-value-to-server-without-form-tag)

Comment: This means that servlet can't access the input elements outside the Forms

Comment: There's probably a way but this is a solution too.

Comment: Can you tell that way